# How can I create a reliable and fast network daemon with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, networking

I am trying to create a Ruby daemon process which clients will be able to connect to.

I need to ensure that the remote Ruby process always remains up and available for connection, so I need to detect network outages or unreachable errors.

I was thinking of having a heartbeat mechanism at the application level between clients and the server, and a timeout in the client if the connection fails.

I was told the `select` method in Ruby could be of help as well but not sure.

Can anyone share any good links/resources or impart some general wisdom to create reliable and fast daemon processes in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a lot of people would use [eventmachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/) for this type of application.  At its core, it uses `epoll` (which is similar to `select`) to decide which socket to deal with next.  There are lots of gems that build on eventmachine to allow you to run different types of servers.  One example is [em-websocket](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket).

Comment: @David: use eventmachine on the client side?

Comment: @Fanatic23, I don't think so.

Comment: On the client side you only have one socket to worry about so you don't need something complicated like eventmachine.  Just use whatever standard networking library comes with your client-side programming environment.